# How the hash in RECORD file of a wheel package is constructed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, python-wheel

I need to know how the RECORD file in a .whl package file is generated. Especially how it generates its sha256 for each files...

For example we can see the line:

```sh
$ cat RECORD | grep WHEEL
pkv-X.Y.Z.dist-info/WHEEL,sha256=X8kVdBCq85ICewwfaE6btv5qKsFQfVq8NYJIXUK0i1A,104
```

which seems come from:

```sh
$ sha256sum <WHEEL | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p | base64 | tr +/ -_ | cut -c -43
X8kVdBCq85ICewwfaE6btv5qKsFQfVq8NYJIXUK0i1A
$ wc -c <WHEEL
104
```

But I would like to know how it is build in python since I have a little trust in the `tr` and `cut -c -43` transform.
note: on other files it "seems" that `tr` is correct i.e. `/` -> `_` and `+` -> `-` but I would like to have the python source code responsible for this...

In python 3.7, I have so far

```sh
python3 -c "import hashlib; import base64; print(base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(open('WHEEL', 'rb').read()).digest()))"
b'X8kVdBCq85ICewwfaE6btv5qKsFQfVq8NYJIXUK0i1A='
```

note: So far I've looked inside https://github.com/pypa/setuptools without any luck...

Comment: `tr...`  seems to come from using `urlsafe_b64decode` instead of `b64encode`

Comment: may comes from https://github.com/pypa/wheel/blob/369b1eeb05f1ce55363afd80edda446a4155d952/wheel/wheelfile.py#L78

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/c9df690f3b5bb285a855953272e6fe24f69aa08a/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py#L71-L84

```py
def rehash(path, blocksize=1 << 20):
    # type: (str, int) -> Tuple[str, str]
    """Return (hash, length) for path using hashlib.sha256()"""
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    length = 0
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        for block in read_chunks(f, size=blocksize):
            length += len(block)
            h.update(block)
    digest = 'sha256=' + urlsafe_b64encode(
        h.digest()
    ).decode('latin1').rstrip('=')
    # unicode/str python2 issues
    return (digest, str(length))  # type: ignore
```

which can be done in manylinux2010 image using the bash command:

```sh
/opt/_internal/cpython-3.7.3/bin/python3 -c "\
import hashlib;\
import base64;\
print(\
 base64.urlsafe_b64encode(\
 hashlib.sha256(open('FILE_NAME', 'rb').read()).digest())\
 .decode('latin1')\
 .rstrip(b'=')\
 )"
```